# Free Service for Alpha Zero training

Tags: keras, training, cloud

I'm an AI student I need to train a deep neural network using the Alpha Zero (Silver et al) for a simple game using this implementation: http://web.stanford.edu/~surag/posts/alphazero.html. I was wondering if any cloud provider like Google or Amazon offers a free trial which suffice to train the model and supports the implementation mentioned above. The game is an Android app called Soccer Stars which is a fairly simple game with simple strategies.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: When you say "supports the implementation" do you mean that it could run the code linked from the article here: https://github.com/suragnair/alpha-zero-general ? That appears to need a dedicated K80 for 3 days for 6x6 Othello . . . I have no idea how long it would need for your game.

Comment: The game I'm working on sounds appears to be simpler to master than ottelo. I reckon it wouldn't need too many epochs to learn proper strategies for it.

Comment: I simply meant if I'd be able to run a Python code that consists of multiple files and different libraries. Time constraints are just given with free services so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to fit your training into a Google Colab session. You can search for tutorials using different libraries, [here is one for PyTorch](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/02/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-tensorflow-keras-pytorch.html). Google Colab is essentially a free online Jupyter notebook, and makes K80 GPU available for acceleration.

Sessions on Colab are limited to ~12 hours maximum, so you would need to start with some simple variants and build up to max allowed training time (this is good practice anyway). There is no guarantee that this will be enough for your game, but you should learn a lot even if the resulting agent is not perfect.

It is not clear whether you have already figured this out, but you most likely will not be able to host the Android App natively to run as the environment, and will need to code some kind of simulation or re-implement the game. I would also assume it is a card, board or turn-based strategy game with perfect information, if you are hoping to use an AlphaZero-based learning agent with it (AlphaZero could probably be adapted to video games, but I would not expect it be as efficient as simpler algorithms without a planning phase, such as A3C in that case).

Comment: Yes, I have re-implemented the game. And yes it is a game with perfect information. I appreciate your help.